# BaseHTTPServer Python and xmlhttprequest authorization

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest, authorization

Sorry, i speak English a little bit.
I have a js code

```
url = '/auth'
var http_request = window.XDomainRequest || window.XMLHttpRequest;
http_request = new http_request;
http_request.open( "post", url, true, 'jack', 'pass_jack' );
http_request.send();
```

And python BaseHTTPServer

```
def do_POST(self):
    if self.path == '/auth':
```

How i can check username and password in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` sets the `Authentication` header, you'd need parse that header:

```
auth = self.headers['Authentication']
```

See [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) (HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access Authentication) for details on how a user agent interacts with a server through that header.